# Why having jobs and waits for them in other thread cause whole application to wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've got a thread pool

```cpp
struct ThreadPool
{
    using Task = std::packaged_task<void()>;

    explicit ThreadPool(size_t workersCount)
    {
        workers.reserve(workersCount);
        for(uint32_t i = 0u; i < workersCount; ++i) {
            workers.emplace_back([=]() {
                while(true) {
                    Task result;
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);
                        condition.wait(locker, [=]() { return stop || !tasks.empty(); });

                        if(stop && tasks.empty()) {
                            break;
                        }

                        result = std::move(tasks.front());
                        tasks.pop();
                    }

                    result();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ~ThreadPool() noexcept
    {
        stop = true;

        condition.notify_all();

        for(auto& worker : workers) {
            worker.join();
        } workers.clear();
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline auto Enqueue(T task)->std::future<decltype(task())>
    {
        auto package = std::packaged_task<decltype(task())()>(std::move(task));
        auto result = package.get_future();
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mutex);
            tasks.emplace(std::move(package));
        }

        condition.notify_one();

        return result;
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    std::queue<Task> tasks;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::atomic_bool stop = false;
};
```

and this example

```cpp
//just for the example this is a global
static ThreadPool pool{4};

struct DoSomethingStruct
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            futures.push_back(pool.Enqueue([this, i]() {
                ints.push_back(i);
            }));
        }

        for(const auto& future : futures) {
            future.wait();
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> ints;
};

int main()
{
    DoSomethingStruct dss;

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        futures.push_back(pool.Enqueue([&dss, i]() {
            dss.DoSomething();
        }));
    }

    for(const auto& future : futures) {
        future.wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the application it never ends.
The example above does not actually present an actual use case. I am wondering why it does not wait for 10 futures in `DoSomethingStruct::DoSomthing();` and then in main for 10 other jobs.

I wanted to do something similar to what this guy did https://wickedengine.net/2018/11/24/simple-job-system-using-standard-c/, but with futures and mutex and condition variable.

Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Isn't `push_back`ing into `dss.ints` from multiple tasks a _data race_? I don't see any synchronization for `ints.push_back(i);`.

Comment: I thought so too, and I wrapped it up around a mutex, but it did not change anything (I mean, maybe it changed something, but the program still did not execute) and in the article I've linked, data is also not protected as I see in its use-case, so I decided to leave it without any protection.

Comment: I also didn't assume that would solve the problem; that's why I posted only a comment about this issue. Note, however, that this issue is also serious, though likely off-topic to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your pool creates 4 working threads. Then, in `main`, you add some tasks into the pool queue, which call `dss.DoSomething();`.

The workers then start executing these tasks. Inside, they first enqueue some more tasks, and **then, they start waiting for their futures forever**. These waits never end since there are no threads that could start resolving the next enqueued tasks.

Creating a thread pool with the ability to enqueue tasks from within processed tasks is not trivial. Basically, what you would need is to **suspend** the current task here instead of waiting. There is no native mechanism for this in C++ (at least, until C++20 coroutines).

As a workaround, you can use OpenMP or Intel TBB, which both provide the described functionality. For example, in OpenMP, you can suspend a current task and wait for its sub-tasks completion with `#pragma omp takswait`.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. So it is like, tasks inside `DoSomething()` won't be executed, because there are not threads that are free to execute them tasks?

Comment: @BrodaJarek3 Yes, if all the 4 threads are waiting at `future.wait();`, which threads then should execute the tasks that only could cause to end that waiting?

Comment: I did not think about it that way. Thanks!